# Expo: cannot get getDevicePushTokenAsync due to non-valid Firebase project ID (Android)

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I just started implementing push notifications in Expo - following the guides on expo.io. Hence, I created an Android app in my [Firebase console and my app.json contains now a reference to the Google service file](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/):

```
"android": {
  "package": "------------",
  "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
  "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
}
```

If I test this on a real android device (standalone app) I do not receive a valid token via this function:

```
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
```

Instead I get the following error:

> Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception
> occured while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on
> module ExpoPushTokenManager: Please set your project ID. A valid
> Firebase project ID is required to communicate with Firebase server
> APIs: It identifies your project with Google."

I guess it has something to do with the way of my project setup. I also followed the Expo guides to [setup firebase](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/) (e.g. for phone authentication) and hence created a web app in the Firebase console. In my application I initialize the Firebase web app with my web app configuration like this:

```
const FIREBASE_CONFIG: IFirebaseOptions = {
  apiKey: '--------',
  authDomain: --------.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://--------.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: '--------',
  storageBucket: '--------.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '--------',
  appId: '--------',
  measurementId: '',
  trackingId: '',
};
    firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
```

The FIREBASE_CONFIG (for my Firebase Web App) as well as the google-services.json (for my Firebase Android App) have the correct project ID. Do I need to initialize the Firebase Android App somehow?

I am using Expo SDK 40.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me: I deleted the old Firebase Android App, created a new one, downloaded the `google-services.json` file and built a new version of my app: It worked.

I cannot come up with an explanation why the first Firebase Android App was faulty because I did not make anything different than I did now.

Hopefully that will help some of you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got this same issue with my react native project. Actually it was working fine but one day this error popped up so I checked the last working version of my files.

The actual issue was with the version of my google services in the gradle file.

Instead on 3.0.0, I have changed it to "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:**4.3.8**'".